# How to detect no volume data with pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, volume

my indicator fail if the symbol have no volume data like SPX or DXY.

How can I detect when there is no volume data to disable my indicator ?

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the cumulative volume until the last bar is zero.

```
if barstate.islast and ta.cum(volume) == 0
    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
volCheck = syminfo.volumetype != "n/a"

if true, volume exists
```